# An analogue of an old proposition

Tags: matrices, fa.functional-analysis

For the absolute value $|C|=(C^*C)^\frac{1}{2}$ and the
Hilbert-Schmidt norm
  $\parallel C\parallel_{HS}=(trC^*C)^\frac{1}{2}$ of the operator $C$. The
following inequality is shown by Araki et al in 'An Inequality for
Hilbert-Schmidt Norm, Commun. Math. Phys. 81, 89-96 (1981)'

> For any two bounded linear operators $A$ and $B$ on a Hilbert space
>   $\mathbb{H}$,
>    $$\parallel |A|-|B| \parallel_{HS}\le
> \sqrt{2}\parallel A-B \parallel_{HS},$$
>   and the factor $\sqrt{2}$ is
>   best possible.

What is the best constant factor $c$ such that
$$\parallel |A|+|B| \parallel_{HS}\ge c\parallel A+B
\parallel_{HS}?$$

Comment: infinity.  Take A to be a non-zero positive operator and B = -A.  Incidentally, either you meant to say "finite dimensional Hilbert space" or you meant "two Hilbert-Schmidt linear operators" since not all bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space have a Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

Comment: Andrew, that doesn't work - the inequality is "the other way round" from what your comment seems to say.

Comment: @Stacey: $A, B$ are arbitrary. In this case, I actually want to determine the maximum of $c$ such that the inequality holds for arbitrary bounded linear operators  $A, B$.

Comment: @Yemon:  Whoops! Just goes to show that "best is in the eye of the beholder".  @Russel: The identity operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space does not have a Hilbert-Schmidt norm.  So for your question to make sense, you need to include some conditions to exclude this case.

Comment: @Stacey: The condition here is the same as in the paper by H.Araki. We allow an operator with norm infinity.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** there is a problem with this, see the comments; I'm leaving this up for the moment in case it helps someone else come along to write a better answer.

---

I'm pretty sure that the inequality
$$ \vert {\rm tr}(A^*B) \vert \leq {\rm tr}( |A| |B| ) $$
holds whenever $A$ and $B$ are Hilbert-Schmidt, just by using the polar decompositions of $A$ and $B$.

If this is the case, then we'd have

$$ \eqalign{
{\rm tr} ((A+B)^*(A+B)) 
&  =  {\rm tr}(A^*A) + {\rm tr}(A^*B) + {\rm tr}(B^*A) + {\rm tr}(B^*B) \\
& \leq {\rm tr}(\vert A\vert^2) + {\rm tr}(\vert A\vert \vert B\vert) + {\rm tr}(\vert B\vert \vert A\vert) + {\rm tr}(\vert B\vert^2) = {\rm tr}((\vert A\vert + \vert B\vert)^2) } $$
which implies that you can get away with $c=1$. Taking $A=B$ to be positive shows that this is sharp.

Comment: I'm not seeing, right now, why `$|tr(A^*B)|\leq tr(|A| |B|)$`.  Can you give a hint...

Comment: It is true $|tr(AB)|\leq tr(|AB|)$, but it is not true in general $tr(|AB|)\leq tr(|A| |B|)$.

Comment: Hmm, I may have been careless here: I was just thinking of putting $A= U \vert A\vert$ and $B=V \vert B\vert$ for partial isometries $U$ and $V$, then ${\rm tr}(A^*B) = {\rm tr} (\vert A\vert U^*V \vert B\vert)$ -- but then I've overlooked the fact that $\vert A\vert \vert B\vert$ might not be positive... Will have to think about this more!